# problems with "Change header background colour when page scrolls"

Tags: jquery, html, css

I read this post on this from Feb. but I am having a problem getting it to work.  I set up an index.html file, copied code from fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/634d6vgq/2/ but am still having problems getting it to work.  I am overlooking something but am not sure what.  I followed everything that was posted in the answer.  Here is the code I set up:

```
<style>

* {margin:0;padding:0}

html {
    background: lightgray;
    height: 5000px;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    height: auto;
    background-color:transparent;  

    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.active { background-color: #fff}

.header.active {
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="header">the header</div>

<script>

$(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $(".header").addClass("active");
        } else {
           $(".header").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});

</script>


</body>
```

Comment: did you add the jquery code to your site?

Comment: Yep, looks like you forgot to include jQuery itself.

Comment: so where should have the jquery been placed?  What is the proper coding for it? So the <script> I have shown is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to include the link to jQuery itself. 
You need to either link it like so

```
  <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Or else download jQuery and link it as such.

To understand the problem more you should take a look at this link.
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp